# Is it safe to use ignite within a closure?

Tags: java, ignite

Im working an ignite service which is going to publishes some tasks via `run`. The service looks like that:

```
public interface MySvc{
    public void foSomeJob();
}

public MySvcImpl implements MySvc, Service{

    @IgniteInstanceResource
    private Ignite ignite;

    public void foSomeJob(){
        IgniteCompute compute = ignite.compute();
        compute.run(() -> {
             ignite.binary()         //<----Is it safe? 
                   .builder("TYPE"); // What is gonna happen on another node
             //build binary object and put it into a cache
        }
    }
}
```

The question is what is going to happen on another node? We serialize the `Ignite` instance (really??) and sent it though the network. Or how is it working?

In my case performance of the task is critical... So I'd like to understand how is it working in case of running the task on the other node?

Maybe I should use `Ignition.ignite();` explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, if you use lambda, it will serialize this ignite object.

Instead of it, you can create class to use it as argument in compute() and use @IgniteInstanceResource annotation in this class.

@IgniteInstanceResource annotation injects a current ignite instance. At the moment of running of this closure you will have an ignite instance, which executes this closure.

Comment: So, yes. `Ignition.localIgnite` would be helpful. But what about `IgniteCache`? Is it safe to use it from a closure? I mean to use a `IgniteCache cache` reference inside a closure when `affinityRun`?

Comment: It's not necessary in this case, you can get IgniteCache object from Ignite by cache(name) or getOrCreateCache methods

Answer (score 3):

`Ignite` instance will be indeed "serialized", and on remote node you will actually get the instance that is local to that node. `Ignite` is not physically sent across network, of course.

Having said that, this code is correct and will work. However, using lambdas or anonymous classes for closures that are sent across network is not a very good practice. I would recommend to create a separate class and inject Ignite using `@IgniteInstanceResource` or `Ignition.ignite()`. This way you will have more control on what is serialized and sent over network. It's safer and better from performance standpoint.

Comment: Inject `@IgniteInstanceResource` in each task? I thought it used reflection. So in cases of large amount of task it would hurt the performance...

Comment: Btw, why not to use `Ignition.localIgnite()`?

Comment: Reflection is not slow if it's done right :) Ignite has a reflection cache that takes care of this. `localIgnite()` is heavier because it has to lookup the name first. With `ignite()` method you provide it explicitly.

Comment: Id like to ask you one more question about clousures. `IgniteCache` retreived outside of a closure and used inside is also being "serialized" and can be used on any other nodes. As far as I understood you use proxies to for `Ignite` and `IgniteCache` instances which makes them "serializable" safely. Right? The question is if it's common to retreive `IgniteCache` outside of `IgniteRunnable` and pass the reference to the cahce into that runnable?

Comment: Not sure what is more common, but my recommendation is in the response :) From my expirience, serialization of `Ignite` or `IgniteCache` very often happens unintentionally due to lack of understanding of what's going on and how anonymous classes and lambdas work.